# WP: Как развернуть полоску цены?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

Подскажите, как правильно развернуть полосу (фильтр) цены на WP в плагине woocommerce? Это нужно для еврейского сайта (RTL).

Вот вывод самого модуля:

```
echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
      <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
        <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div class="price_slider_amount">

          <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="' . esc_attr( $max_price ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
<input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="' . esc_attr( $min_price ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__('Min price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
          <button type="submit" class="button">' . __( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
          <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
            ' . __( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="to"></span> &mdash; <span class="from"></span>
          </div>
          ' . $fields . '
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>';

    $this->widget_end( $args );
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я поменял местами блоки max_price и min_price - результата нет.

Как решить вопрос?

Comment: а если в css - `direction: rtl;` сделать?

Comment: на ползунок не влияет (((

Comment: Вы можете привести рабочий пример этого блока с полоской?